# .fetch() collection backbone.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-local-storage

I want to call API URL to get data, and pass it to a view, but encounter an error when using fetch property:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined  
    at G.d.Backbone.sync (backbone.localStorage-min.js:8)  
    at G.d.fetch (backbone-min.js:23)  
    at G.d.initialize (backbone:120)  
    at G.d.g.Collection (backbone-min.js:18)  
    at new G.d (backbone-min.js:38)  
    at backbone:137
```

**The code:**

```js
var app = {};
app.postCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  initialize: function(){
    this.fetch({
      success: this.fetchSuccess,
      error: this.fetchError
    });
  },

  fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
    console.log('Collection fetch success', response.data);
    /*console.log('Collection models: ', this.models);*/
  },

  fetchError: function (collection, response) {
    throw new Error(" fetch error");
  }

});

try {
  app.postcollection = new app.postCollection();
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of localStorage. Update to a new version, for example `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.16/backbone.localStorage.js`

Also, you need to specify `localStorage` property on the collection like `localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeCollection"),`

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q39076jk/2/)